# React Native: .env file values aren't being read with react-native-config

Tags: react-native, react-native-config

I'm rebuilding my Expo app in pure React Native and trying to figure out the environment variable situation. I'm trying out react-native-config, currently on "^1.5.1". I installed using `yarn add react-native-config` and then I did `npx pod-install`.

Here is my .env file:

```
ENV_NAME=prod
TEST_ENV_VAR=hello
```

And for one of my components, I have code like this:

```
import Config from "react-native-config";

export function LoginScreen({ navigation }) {
   ...
   const [isDev, setIsDev] = React.useState(Config.ENV_NAME === 'dev')
   const [testEnvString, setTestEnvString] = useState(Config.TEST_ENV_VAR)
   ...

   return (
      ...
        {isDev ? 
        <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text>Debug info: {isDev}</Text>
            <Text>Test string: {testEnvString}</Text>
        </View>
        : null}
      ...
   )
```

What I'm finding is that:

- `isDev` always evaluates to true, ie that snippet in the return ( ) is always showing, even when the .env file has ENV_NAME=prod
- `isDev` does not itself show up as a value after the string "Debug info: " - so it's some kind of value that shows up as blank but evaluates to true
- `testEnvString` also does not show up in the displayed component

Am I missing anything in my setup here?

Addendum: I'm testing on iOS simulator (I don't care about Android yet) with `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using Expo so its docs mention about the use of the `process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_[VARNAME]` reference [here](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/environment-variables/#how-variables-are-loaded) if you are going to display the environment variables publicly.

Comment: Actually the opposite - I am rebuilding my Expo app NOT on Expo :) Eventually hit too many limitations with Expo, so I'm porting my app over to core React Native

Comment: @AllenY does it work if you rename the env variable to the one suggested above? if it works, it may mean that the expo ejection is not done correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your iOS build and then rebuilding. From my experience, `.env` or change to `.env` is not loaded until the project is completely rebuilt from scratch.

[react-native-clean-project](https://github.com/pmadruga/react-native-clean-project) is a handy tool to perform the cleaning task. Follow the instruction to install, run `npm run clean`, and answer yes only to "Wipe iOS build folder". Once the cleaning is done, rebuild the app and you shall see the values `.env`.

One caveat of using react-native-clean-project is that it favors interactive prompt. There are non-interactive flags, but they are quite lacking. Thus, if you want to do the cleaning non-interactively, run the following command (copied from [here](https://github.com/pmadruga/react-native-clean-project/blob/876920f3413f80f6f3bdce1fe1be2c141b569345/source/internals/tasks.js#L5)):

```
rm -rf ios/build && (killall Xcode || true) && xcrun -k && cd ios && xcodebuild -alltargets clean && cd .. && rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache" && rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang.$(whoami)/ModuleCache" && rm -fr ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ && rm -fr ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/
```